# Raspberry pi3 TFT screen setup

Tags: linux, lcd, raspbian

EDIT: [This](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Latest-Raspberry-Pi-3-Model-B-3-5-inch-Touchscreen-480-320-TFT-LCD-ABS-Case/32905169780.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dhHhq4L) is the the screen I bought

This is my first post here so I hope I do not screw up too much...

I have a raspberry pi3 with 3.5inch tft resistive touchscreen display (720x480) connected via SPI (GPIO pins).

I would like to use it for a project, but the problem is that the screen is too small and windows cant fit inside. I need to fit at least 1280x720 (1920x1080 would be better) into a 720x480 screen.

The screen is installed using [this repository](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show) and I have already tried things mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891235/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-raspberry-pi). I am currently at a loss for what to try next. I will also attach my current /boot/config.txt file, to make it easier to explain what to do.

Thanks in advance for any tips and suggestions.

my /boot/config.txt file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=1920
framebuffer_height=1080

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_cvt=1024 720 60 1 0 0 0

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=tft35a
#dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=17,penirq_pull=2,speed=1000000,keep_vref_on=1,swapxy=1,pmax=255,xohms=60,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Comment: I assume you mean this TFT screen? If so here is a tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/easy-install-2 Also FYI there are images at the bottom that have everything already good to go if you just want the screen to work

Comment: Check my edit, it is a different screen. Also check the github link.

Comment: Check my edit. It is the exact one I ordered.

Comment: Hm sorry I am not any help past what you tried. Hopefully someone else comes along to help

Comment: No problem, I aprreciate that you at least tried.

Comment: Have you tried using `xinput-calibrator`?

Comment: No I have not, I am going to right now.

Comment: I have used it before on a larger touch screen that helped me obtain HD resolution so perhaps it will be helpful for you as well. There is far better documentation out there on how to properly use it than I can provide though

Comment: I do not see how calibrating is supposed to help, is there another function that I missed or what?

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=143581

The screen in your link uses a XPT2046 chip. Seems that this line is required in the `/boot/config.txt` file:

```
dtoverlay=ads7846,penirq=25,speed=10000,penirq_pull=2,xohms=150
```

The parameters for the framebuffer (width and height) could be a problem, try commenting them out by adding a # in the first position of each line, then the default will be chosen automatically.

Hopefully it will work, my screen is ordered, so I have not yet had a chance to test this.